# Java NullPointException - Error while initializing managers

Tags: windows-7, java, 32-bit

Have a big issue here and need your help. Java seems to be breaking on a number of laptops here at work.

**Error log:**

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@13c765e
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.40
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.40
network: Cache entry found [url: http://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp
temp: new XMLParser with source:
temp: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="https://java.com/en/download/" href="JavaDetection_applet.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Java Detection</title>
        <vendor>Oracle Inc.</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
  <j2se version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="JavaDetection.jar" />
    </resources>
 <security>
  <all-permissions /> 
 </security>
    <applet-desc 
         name="Java Detection Applet"
         main-class="JavaDetection"
         width="1"
         height="1">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
temp: 
returning ROOT as follows:
<jnlp codebase="https://java.com/en/download/" href="JavaDetection_applet.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
  <information>
    <title>Java Detection</title>
    <vendor>Oracle Inc.</vendor>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="JavaDetection.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <applet-desc name="Java Detection Applet" main-class="JavaDetection" width="1" height="1"/>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
network: Created version ID: 1.6+
network: Created version ID: 1.9
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://java.com/en/download/" href="https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Java Detection</title>
    <vendor>Oracle Inc.</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="Java Detection Applet" main-class="JavaDetection" documentbase="http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre" width="1" height="1"/>
</jnlp>
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null]
network: Connecting https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunec.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Connecting https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null]
network: Connecting https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null]
network: Connecting https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Connecting https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp, version: null]
network: Connecting https://java.com/en/download/JavaDetection_applet.jnlp with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while initializing manager: java.lang.NullPointerException, bail out
```

([Error log on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dr7yzgvX))

It was working fine but there were a number of Windows Updates pending. Restarted and Java broke. Has anyone experienced this issue as well? I tried uninstalling the KBs individually and after removing **KB2876331**, Java worked for a bit. Restarted and Java broke again.

*Things I’ve tried:*

1. Uninstall of Java completely from laptop and reinstall, both offline package install and directly from the Java site (Not successful)
2. Uninstalled Java, reinstalled only 64 bit. (Not successful)
3. Uninstalled 64 bit then reinstalled 32 bit (Not successful)
4. Uninstalled Java completely, ran Microsoft fix it utility and reinstalled (Not successful)
5. Uninstalled Java and used a utility called JavaRa to uninstall remaining components: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1560-remove-previous-versions-of-java-with-javara (Not succesful)
6. Ran the install to install java from the same utility JavaRa. It installs Java 6 and that funny enough ends up working!
7. Tried to update Java 6 from the java console to Java 7 Update 45 and it breaks again (Not successful)
8. Also tried deleting anything I could for java (folders/registry search) after an uninstall to make sure it was as clean as could be. (Not successful)
9. Tried Revo Uninstaller to remove Java, didn’t get me any further.

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a config thing rather than a problem with Java itself, in the log it says:

> network: Connecting http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

This says to me that you are connecting using http (although on port 443) but trying to open an SSL connection. Try https instead of http? Try connecting to that site yourself with a browser and see what actual connection you get.

Answer (score 1):

I just had what looks like the same problem, after upgrading to Java 7 Update 51 (32-bit), in IE10 on 64-bit Windows 8. With logging and tracing on, the last 10 lines of the log are essentially the same as yours, except in my case the .jnlp cache entry was out of date rather than missing. As Tim B spotted, it was trying to connect to http://java.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT.

The solution here was to turn on IE's proxy - we're behind a MS firewall. Earlier this hasn't been a problem for applets, as Microsoft Firewall Client for ISA Server has handled the traffic.

I've had KB2876331 for over a month, so that's probably not related, but I did get a bunch of other MS updates the other day.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Java 7u79 applets stopped working for me. I needed two things:

1. Machine restart
2. Firewall reconfiguration - a new application (`jre7\bin\jp2launcher.exe`) needed network connections

Answer (score -1):

After many attempts, I managed to solve the problem by full removing the version 8 of Java and install Java 7u80.

Hope this can help you!

Daniel